# How can I view a list of all files with conflicts in a Tortoise SVN Repository?

Tags: tortoisesvn, conflict

Is there any way to get a list of files that are in a (SVN) conflicted state using Tortoise SVN?

Comment: Wish I knew. No idea why this isn't a prominent menu option.

Comment: Aha! Found it. Answer below.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To do this, right-click on the **folder** containing the conflicts you wish to see, then click `Resolve...`.

[image: TortoiseSVN right-click menu from version 1.8.8]

Note that this is something of a side-effect, since this option is (generally) for marking conflicts as resolved. It is also, however, intended to help you actually find and resolve the conflicts. The behavior is as follows:

A window will appear that lists all the file conflicts, with check-boxes next to them. If you double-click on a file name, Tortoise will bring up the Merge window for that file. When you've selected the files you want to mark as resolved (using the check-boxes), you can do so by clicking "Ok," or you can simply exit the window without changing the resolution status of any conflicts by clicking "Cancel."

Comment: You are **totally wrong**. "Resolved" in menu mark file as "resolved" after it had "conflicted" state

Comment: @Lazy Badger: no, choose "Resolved" (not "mark resolved") after right clicking on a **folder**, not a particular file. Try it; yes, you use the option to resolve the conflicts it shows, but it **does** show the conflicts.

Comment: @Poldie Huh, looks like you're right. I'm not sure if this has changed in the last year or if I just misread it. Thanks.

Comment: @KyleStrand No worries - your answer helped me this morning!

Comment: @KyleStrand Even after your edits, I didn't notice the **folder** bit in the answer. I updated it to use a more active tone.

Comment: @jpaugh Fair enough. I was just reviewing your edit and it seems entirely reasonable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with TSVN, but it's rather easy for CLI-interface.

Just use `svn status` inside your WC and check output:

```
  The first seven columns in the output are each one character wide:
    First column: Says if item was added, deleted, or otherwise changed
    ...
      'C' Conflicted
```

Comment: No, you don't have to use the command-line. My answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Inside "Check for modifications" theres another button...

[image: TortoiseSVN right-click menu from version 1.8.8]

... "check repository" it will show conflicts
[image: https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/images/RepoStatus.png]

This is [my source](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-wcstatus.html)