# TortoiseSVN - Merge - How to resume resolving unresolved conflicts?

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn, resume

I performed a normal "Merge a range of revisions" merge to merge a branch in SVN into the working copy of a different branch (using the currently latest TortoiseSVN).

I accidentally closed the window showing all unresolved conflicts and I only had some of the files merged but some of them were time consuming to merge so I don't want to start over.

How can I resume the merge? Attempting to perform the merge again on the local copy that already had a merge performed, unsurprisingly gives the warning: "The target working copy has local modifications!".

I can't find anything remotely related to this problem on google. Thanks

Comment: I may have found a solution: Right click on the project folder -> TortoiseSVN -> Resolve...
This looks like the list of incomplete files but I need to go through to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Right click on the project folder -> TortoiseSVN -> Resolve...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPUrS.png)

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527784/how-can-i-view-a-list-of-all-files-with-conflicts-in-a-tortoise-svn-repository)

Answer (score 2):

The "check for modifications" dialog, or the command-line `svn status` will show you any conflicted files as well as files modified without conflict during the merge, so that you can check the results.

Double click conflicted files in the dialog to resolve the conflict.

Comment: Someone at work also mentioned this but I did not try it since I found a solution